# Visual Studio 2022 -> Tried to install Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices.vsix fails with errors on user and service

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, analysisservices

I tried to run Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices.vsix as I need tools to connect to a server-side Analysis Services in order to create and define a star/snowflake schema for a new OLAP cube.

I have just obtained VS2022, a pre-requisite for the pack, and the install gets some way before stopping with an error.

Has anyone experienced this?

As the installers work therefore URLs must be whitelisted already (I am on client site at work) and i do not wish to login with my own MS account as this VS2022 has a corporate licence.

Here is the error from the log:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeDeveloperTools.WindowsIdentityFoundation.Msu:
> The current OS Version '10.0.18363.0' is not in the supported version
> range '(,6.2)'. 20/05/2022 14:18:40 - Package
> 'sqllocaldb2019,version=17.0.62110.20190,chip=x64,language=en-US'
> failed to download from
> 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/18a24c82-eca2-4cdf-981e-7713ad6ce07c/c11175b84807c159d627495cf5ac53cd707c8ed7422bf946f30688c11434e5f8/SqlLocalDB.msi'.
> WebClient download failed: Unable to connect to the remote server.
> Bits download failed: The operation being requested was not performed
> because the user has not logged on to the network. The specified
> service does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704DD). WinInet
> download failed: Function: InternetOpenUrl, HR: -2147012867, Message:
> Unknown error 12029, Signature:
> PackageId=sqllocaldb2019;PackageAction=DownloadPackage;ReturnCode=0x80131500
> 20/05/2022 14:18:40 - Skipping download of package
> 'SSDT,version=17.0.62110.20190,productarch=neutral' since the package
> or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022 14:18:40 -
> Skipping download of package
> 'SSDT.amd64,version=17.0.62110.20190,productarch=x64' since the
> package or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022 14:18:40 -
> Skipping download of package
> '89387616-73c8-4223-a360-f36c90a01f6b,version=3.0.3' since the package
> or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022 14:20:03 - Package
> 'msodbcsql,version=17.0.62110.20190,chip=x64,language=en-US' failed to
> download from
> 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/81e051b5-3f88-4473-b7f0-a696b9268be5/174a46541461c32552d9b5256628b7e42ef128d1105682e69e75ecadd5cb3708/msodbcsql.msi'.
> WebClient download failed: Unable to connect to the remote server.
> Bits download failed: The operation being requested was not performed
> because the user has not logged on to the network. The specified
> service does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704DD). WinInet
> download failed: Function: InternetOpenUrl, HR: -2147012867, Message:
> Unknown error 12029, Signature:
> PackageId=msodbcsql;PackageAction=DownloadPackage;ReturnCode=0x80131500
> 20/05/2022 14:20:03 - Skipping Install of
> 'msodbcsql,version=17.0.62110.20190,chip=x64,language=en-US' since
> downloading it failed. 20/05/2022 14:20:03 - Skipping cache of package
> 'msodbcsql,version=17.0.62110.20190,chip=x64,language=en-US' since the
> package or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022 14:20:03 -
> Skipping cache of package
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.MSODBC.SQL,version=17.0.31804.368'
> since the package or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022
> 14:20:03 - Skipping Install of
> 'sqllocaldb2019,version=17.0.62110.20190,chip=x64,language=en-US'
> since downloading it failed. 20/05/2022 14:20:03 - Skipping cache of
> package
> 'sqllocaldb2019,version=17.0.62110.20190,chip=x64,language=en-US'
> since the package or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022
> 14:20:03 - Skipping cache of package
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.LocalDB.Runtime,version=17.0.31804.368'
> since the package or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022
> 14:20:03 - Skipping Install of
> 'SSDT,version=17.0.62110.20190,productarch=neutral' since the package
> or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022 14:20:03 -
> Skipping cache of package
> 'SSDT,version=17.0.62110.20190,productarch=neutral' since the package
> or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022 14:20:03 -
> Skipping Install of
> 'SSDT.amd64,version=17.0.62110.20190,productarch=x64' since the
> package or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022 14:20:03 -
> Skipping cache of package
> 'SSDT.amd64,version=17.0.62110.20190,productarch=x64' since the
> package or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022 14:20:03 -
> Skipping cache of package
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Common.Azure.Tools,version=17.0.31804.368'
> since the package or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022
> 14:20:04 - Skipping cache of package
> 'MsSqlCmdLnUtils,version=17.0.62110.20190,chip=x64,language=en-US'
> since the package or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022
> 14:20:04 - Skipping cache of package
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.MSSQL.CMDLnUtils,version=17.0.31804.368'
> since the package or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022
> 14:20:04 - Skipping cache of package
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=17.0.31804.368'
> since the package or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022
> 14:20:06 - Skipping Install of
> '89387616-73c8-4223-a360-f36c90a01f6b,version=3.0.3' since the package
> or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022 14:20:06 -
> Skipping cache of package
> '89387616-73c8-4223-a360-f36c90a01f6b,version=3.0.3' since the package
> or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022 14:20:06 -
> Skipping cache of package
> 'Component.89387616-73c8-4223-a360-f36c90a01f6b,version=3.0.3' since
> the package or a parent package had a vital failure. 20/05/2022
> 14:21:54 - Install Error : System.AggregateException: One or more
> errors occurred. --->
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PackageFailureException: Package
> 'msodbcsql' failed to download;Package 'sqllocaldb2019' failed to
> download    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Run(CancellationToken
> token)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunOperation(InstallOperation
> installOperation, CancellationToken token, ExecuteAction action,
> ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunCoreOperation(InstallOperation
> coreOperation, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation
> telemetryOperation, CancellationToken token)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String
> destination, CancellationToken token)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.b__14_0()
> in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\product\extensionManager\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine\SetupEngine\SetupEngineService.cs:line
> 50    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.Install() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\product\extensionManager\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine\SetupEngine\SetupEngineService.cs:line 50    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallModule.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags
> installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion,
> IInstalledExtension& newExtension) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\product\extensionManager\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine\Impl\EngineModules\InstallModule.cs:line
> 1023    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallModule.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl
> extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar,
> IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList,
> AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress, Version
> targetedVsVersion) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\product\extensionManager\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine\Impl\EngineModules\InstallModule.cs:line
> 265    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallModule.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension
> installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation
> asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\product\extensionManager\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine\Impl\EngineModules\InstallModule.cs:line
> 399    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallModule.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension
> extension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\product\extensionManager\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine\Impl\EngineModules\InstallModule.cs:line
> 894 ---> (Inner Exception #0)
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PackageFailureException: Package
> 'msodbcsql' failed to download;Package 'sqllocaldb2019' failed to
> download    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Run(CancellationToken
> token)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunOperation(InstallOperation
> installOperation, CancellationToken token, ExecuteAction action,
> ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunCoreOperation(InstallOperation
> coreOperation, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation
> telemetryOperation, CancellationToken token)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String
> destination, CancellationToken token)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.b__14_0()
> in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by setting VS2022 to run in Admin mode (in properties | advanced on right-click on Start Menu icon).

Then I launched a Dev powershell from inside VS2022 then ran:

VSIXInstaller.exe /admin /force

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.